# Access private image registry for a GitHub Action

Tags: docker, github-actions

Is there a way to use private images from a registry with authentication for custom GitHub Docker container actions? Would like to point at runs.image to a private docker image. Ideally, one which is uploaded to a GitHub Packages registry.

```
# action.yml
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone'
inputs:
  who_to_greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: true
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  time: # id of output
    description: 'The time we greeted you'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.who_to_greet }}
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? It seems like it should be possible but I haven't been able to figure out the right magic spell

Comment: I asked the same question in the new GitHub Community, too and only got this disappointing answer: Only public images (or local Dockerfiles) are supported.